# Why is my AJAX data empty, even if the output of the variable before ajax is right?

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#p").change(function () {
        var p_id = $(this).val();
        console.log(p_id);     //<-------
        $.ajax({
            url: "m/a/a.class.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {pId: p_id},
            dataType: "text",

            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data); //<------
            }
        });

    });
```

I want to pass the my data to PHP, but when I am trying to use it for a query it is empty, so I added the `console.log` before and after the AJAX script.

Before it gives me the right value `("id")` of the selected product, for example "9", but the `console.log` in the AJAX script just returns an empty value "".

What is the problem with this? Do I miss-understand the code of AJAX?

UPDATE:

```
case 'linie':
               if (isset($_POST['pId'])){
                $t = $_POST['pId'];
                }
                $sql = 'SELECT l.id, l.bezeichnung as bezeichnung '
                    . 'FROM l  "
                    . 'LEFT JOIN p ON p.id=l.p_id '
                    . 'WHERE l.p_id ="'.$t.'" AND l.deleted=0 AND p.deleted=0  '
                    . 'ORDER BY l.bezeichnung ';
                break;
```

This is the relevant part of my PHP code where I try to get the previous input.

UPDATE 2:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#p").change(function () {
        var p_id = $(this).val();
         console.log(p_id);
         $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "m/a/a.class.php",
        data: { pID: $('#p').val() },
        async: true,
        dataType: 'text', (...)
```

When I changed it to this it worked for me :)

Comment: `data` will be whatever text your PHP page sends back. Is it sending anything back? Look in the network console.

Comment: Presumably because `modules/ausschuss/ausschuss.class.php` (which doesn't look like a PHP script that is intended to be requested directly by a browser) doesn't output anything. What do you expect it to output. What code does it contain?

Comment: It contains the querys which fill the selects and provides every pages and other functions for my app. It is the php file where i want to use the $_POST['produktId'. I will try to look in the network console first.

Comment: would you mind to share with us the relevant part of the php code?

Comment: @LelioFaieta I just added it above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I am not really sure where to look for the answer in the network console, so i didn't find anything.

Comment: you are inside a switch that looks for a value of 'linie'. Where is that coming from? Probably you need to pass it in your ajax call or you will never enter this piece of code

Comment: @mike123 — It's case insensitive. Please don't throw wild guesses about.

Comment: "This is the relevant part of my PHP code" — It's vulnerable to SQL injection (or would be if you ever passed that SQL to a database) and doesn't output anything.

Comment: @mike123 — One of those (method and type) is an alias for the other.

Comment: @LelioFaieta It is a switch for the different queries since i am using 4 Selectpickers, so in every case it shows the belonging data. Since my main problem is that i don't even get an output in the console, i can't judge if it enters this piece of code or not.

Comment: i am telling you it doesn't if you don't provide a value for the variable you use in the switch: and you are not doing it

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are playing data data.

This data

```
data: {produktId: p_id},
```

is not same as this data

```
success: function (data) {
```

Better way of writing it will be

```
$("#produkt").change(function () {
        var p_id = $(this).val();
        console.log(p_id);     //<-------
        $.ajax({
            url: "modules/ausschuss/ausschuss.class.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {produktId: p_id},
            dataType: "text",

            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response); //<------
            }
        });

    });
```

Notice the `success` block parameter

So this data `data: {produktId: p_id},`  is detail which you pass to an ajax call.

And the ajax call may or may not return response which is returned in success block as `response`.

[Example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax)

Comment: First of all thank you. I tried it but it still gives me an empty output. Like before I get the ID of the selected product, and below an empty result